# WordPress Plugin Function

Tags: wordpress

I had a developer write this plugin for me to add functionality to import bulk pricing to products through WP All Import, a while back. He has not been getting back to me regarding this. I had to delete the auto import that we had set up together and I don't remember how to use it to import the bulk pricing with the system he built. Could someone explain what the code indicate that I would do to use it?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WP All Import Woo Bulk Pricing Add-On
Description: Import data related to bulk pricing
Version: 1.0    */
//  

function import_pricing_fields($id, $xml_node) {
    // return;
    $post_type = get_post_type($id);

    if($post_type == 'product' || $post_type == 'product_variation' ){
        $xml_node = (array) $xml_node;
        $_product = wc_get_product( $id );
        $number_of_prices = 3;
        if( $_product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
            update_post_meta($id,'_regular_price', $xml_node['price']);
            update_post_meta($id,'_price', $xml_node['price']);
            $pricing_array = array();
            for($i=1;$i<$number_of_prices;$i++){
                if(isset($xml_node['qb_'.$i]) && $xml_node['qb_'.$i] != 0){
                    $pricing_array[$i]['min'] = $xml_node['qb_'.$i];
                    if($i > 1){
                        $pricing_array[$i-1]['max'] = $xml_node['qb_'.$i]-1;
                        $pricing_array[$i]['max'] = "*";
                    } else {
                        $pricing_array[$i]['max'] = "*";
                    }
                    $pricing_array[$i]['val'] = $xml_node['price_'.$i];
                }
            }
            $pricing_array = array_values($pricing_array);


            if(!empty($pricing_array)) {
                update_post_meta($id,'_wc_bulk_pricing_ruleset','_custom');
                update_post_meta($id,'_wc_bulk_pricing_custom_ruleset', $pricing_array);
            }
        } else{
            $var_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($xml_node['catalog']);
            $variations = $_product->get_children();

            if(!empty($variations)) {
                foreach ($variations as $variation) {
                    $sku = get_post_meta($variation, '_sku', true);
                    if(!empty($sku) && $sku == $xml_node['catalog']) {
                        $var_id = $variation;
                    }
                }
            }


            update_post_meta($var_id,'_regular_price', $xml_node['price']);
            update_post_meta($var_id,'_price', $xml_node['price']);
            if(isset($xml_node['qb_1'])) {
                $pricing_array = array();
                for($i=1;$i<$number_of_prices;$i++){
                    if(isset($xml_node['qb_'.$i]) && $xml_node['qb_'.$i] != 0){
                        $pricing_array[$i]['min'] = $xml_node['qb_'.$i];
                        if($i > 1){
                            $pricing_array[$i-1]['max'] = $xml_node['qb_'.$i]-1;
                            $pricing_array[$i]['max'] = "*";
                        } else {
                            $pricing_array[$i]['max'] = "*";
                        }
                        $pricing_array[$i]['val'] = $xml_node['price_'.$i];
                    }
                }
                $pricing_array = array_values($pricing_array);


                if(!empty($pricing_array)) {
                    update_post_meta($var_id,'_wc_bulk_pricing_ruleset','_custom');
                    update_post_meta($var_id,'_wc_bulk_pricing_custom_ruleset', $pricing_array);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
add_action('pmxi_saved_post','import_pricing_fields', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone explain what the code indicate that I would do to use
>   it?

The function `import_pricing_fields()` is hooked into the `'pmxi_saved_post'` action.

http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/action-reference/

What this means is that every time you import a `post` using WP All Import it will also run the function `import_pricing_fields()`.

However this is one check to pass before the majority of the code in this function will run, and that is on line 4 `if($post_type == 'product' || $post_type == 'product_variation' )`. Which simply means if the `post` is a `product` or `product_variation` continue running this code.

The rest of the code looks like it does what you said, import bulk pricing...

Comment: Thank you. The programmer that built this didn't explain and has ignored all my emails regarding this and I've been trying to utilize its function but what I had requested was not what he had done.